# How to generate an RGB Histogram by opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I want to do a feature extraction from an image to a 3D histogram in the RGB colorspace. I have the following python code which I want to do it under c++:

```
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], None, self.bins, [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])        
hist = cv2.normalize(hist)
return hist.flatten()
```

I did something like this:

```
float range[] = { 0, 255 } ;   
const float* histRange = { range };
int channels[] = {0};
cv::calcHist( &image, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), r_hist, 1, &sizeVector[0], &histRange);
channels[0] = 1;
cv::calcHist( &image, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), g_hist, 1, &sizeVector[0], &histRange);
channels[0] = 2;
cv::calcHist( &image, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), b_hist, 1, &sizeVector[0], &histRange);
```

But then I found that they are not the same since in python the histogram is counting in 3D-based, how to convert the code to c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code example from OpenCv documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html#code

The approach here is to split the three channels first and then calculate the histogram for each channel.

For a 3D histogram, refer to this answer:

[How to access 3D Histogram values in C++ using OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421806/how-to-access-3d-histogram-values-in-c-using-opencv)

Comment: It seems that this code cannot do what I want. In the python, every point will be counted once. But if I split it into three plants and count them one by one, then every point will be counted three times.

Comment: You can normalise histograms, so a point counted three times is actually fine. Since every pixel must have all three values, it should not cause an error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean~"~ I mean if I have a point that belongs to Bin_{r}(1) and Bin_{g}(4) and Bin_{b}(6). By the python code, I will have a 3D histogram that count this point into a bin [1, 4, 6], for an example. But if I do it in c++ by splitting method, how can I merge the result back?

Comment: Sorry, I finally got it. If you need a 3D histogram, you cannot get it using this method. But you can write your own code to do that. I think the code here tries that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421806/how-to-access-3d-histogram-values-in-c-using-opencv. Updated the answer with this, so that it is useful to others as well.